# can't locate the database file

Tags: python, mysql, blob

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'prototype.db'

I get this error each time I run python database.py which is the name of the file and Prototype.db  is the name of the database file.
any help?

here's the code for  the database.py file

```
import mysql.connector

#to create a database instance
MyDB = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "Localhost",
    database = "Prototype.db",
    user = "root",
    password = ""
    )


#a cursor is an object we use to interact with the database
MyCursor = MyDB.cursor()

MyCursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Images (id INTEGER(45) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Photo BLOB NOT NULL")

#to select the file to upload
def InsertBlob(FilePath):
    with open(FilePath, "rb") as File:
        BinaryData = File.read()
    SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO Images (Photo) VALUES (%s)"
    MyCursor.execute(SQLStatement, (BinaryData, ) )
    MyDB.commit()

def RetrieveBlob(ID):
    SQLStatement2 = "SELECT * FROM Images WHERE id = {0}"
    MyCursor.execute(SQLStatement2.format(str(ID)))
    MyResult = MyCursor.fetchone()[1]
    StoreFilePath = "IMG/img{0}.jpg".format(str(ID))
    print(MyResult)
    
    with open(StoreFilePath, "wb") as File:
        File.write(MyResult)
        File.close()


#a menu to help us input data
print("1. Insert Image\n2. Read Image")
MenuInput = input()

if int(MenuInput) ==1:
    UserFilePath = input("Enter File Path:")
    InsertBlob(UserFilePath)
elif int(MenuInput) ==2:
    UserIDChoice = input("Enter ID:")
    RetrieveBlob(UserIDChoice)
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't represent databases as files externally. Try to omit ".db".

Answer (score 0):

Your database name might not be exactly the same, try to copy the exact name from the server if you're using it to view the database list. Make sure, it will only connect to the database if the name of the database is same as what you created using your DBMS. Also in case you changes your port number then you need to provide port as well.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong

```
Prototype.db
```

means database Prototype and table db

so check in your server which databases exist

with `SHOW DATABASES;`

i think it must be

> Prototype

without any attached text, but better check first